# R Shiny: req() *at least one of* multiple objects/values

Tags: r, validation, shiny

Sorry if this is simple but I'm not able to find an answer. I'm new to using validate/req. In my shiny app I have currently:

```
myfx <- reactive({
    req(c(input$value, data1(), data2()) )
    ...
})
```

This ensures all values are truthy before executing. But what I want is to require the input and *at least one of the data* values. How can I make something like this work?

```
myfx <- reactive({
        req(c(input$value, any_of(data1(), data2())) )
        ...
    })
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`req` will work as long as its argument(s) resolves to something "Truthy", but it always assumes "AND". To get an "OR", I think you need to take over some of the tests manually, perhaps something like:

```r
myfx <- reactive({
  req(
    isTruthy(input$value),
    isTruthy(data1()) || isTruthy(data2())
  )
  ...
})
```

(That's [`shiny::isTruthy`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/req.html), if you want to read more about it. Currently at version 1.6.0, I don't see that function changing any time soon.)

Comment: thx this is what I needed. I am opening a new question for the next one: how to test inside if() whether the optional reactive values exist.