# How to build a shiny app that shows the output ONLY when the user clicks a click button?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to build a simple `shiny` app, that takes a number `input$number` and prints this number **only** when the user clicks (`input$click`).

So far, I have tried this:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
        sliderInput("number", "number", value = 10, min = 0, max = 50),
        actionButton("click", "Change output"),
        textOutput("text")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
        
        observeEvent(input$click, {
                output$text = renderText({
                        print(input$number)
                })
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the app launches for the first time, it waits for the user to click before it shows the output `text`. However, after clicking for the first time, the app does not care if you click or not, it will automatically show the chosen number with slider.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isolate` to prevent reactivity

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("number", "number", value = 10, min = 0, max = 50),
  actionButton("click", "Change output"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$text = renderText({
      input$click
      req(input$click) #to prevent print at first lauch
      isolate(print(input$number))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: More examples : https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that I find helpful is to store values in a `reactiveValues` list and then update them using event observers.

```
library(shiny)

SLIDER_INIT <- 10

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("number", "number", value = SLIDER_INIT, min = 0, max = 50),
  actionButton("click", "Change output"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Store values that will need to be displayed to the user here.
  AppValues <- reactiveValues(
    slider_number = 10
  )
  
  # Change reactive values only when an event occurs.
  observeEvent(
    input$click, 
    {
      AppValues$slider_number <- input$number
    }
  )
  
  # Display the current value for the user.
  output$text = renderText({
    AppValues$slider_number
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: if this `actionButton` is inside a Shiny modal. when the modal is rendered, this counts as the `actionButton` being clicked, and triggers the `observeEvent`. How can we run the operation specifically when the button is clicked?

Comment: What I did was add `shiny::req(shiny::isTruthy(input$button))`  like shown in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472990/r-shiny-req-at-least-one-of-multiple-objects-values